# Trying to do multidimentional array in PHP but something going wrong

Tags: php

I have an array that I declare like this:

```
$health_array = array( );
```

For every iteration I try to put these 3 items in it like this:

```
$health_array["num_problems"] = $num_problems;
$health_array["category_id"] = $category_id;
$health_array["category_name"] = $category_name;
```

But when I loop through the array I get gibberish. Here is how I loop through it:

```
foreach ($health_array as $i => $row)
{
    echo  '<p>'.$row['category_name'].' '.$row['category_id'].' '.$row['num_problems'].'</p>';
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can we see what your output looks like?

Comment: what is the expected outcome and what are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you want to do a multi-dimensional array and you're creating a monodimensional one, by overwriting each time the same 3 elements.

You should do something like:

```
$health_array = array();
$tmp = array();

$tmp["num_problems"] = 5;
$tmp["category_id"] = 8;
$tmp["category_name"] = "something";
$health_array[] = $tmp;

$tmp["num_problems"] = 15;
$tmp["category_id"] = 22;
$tmp["category_name"] = "something else";
$health_array[] = $tmp;

foreach ($health_array as $h)
    {
    echo $h["num_problems"]." - ".$h["category_id"]." - ".$h["category_name"]."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> For every iteration I try to put these 3 items in it like this:
>
> $health_array["num_problems"] = $num_problems;
> $health_array["category_id"] = $category_id;
> $health_array["category_name"] = $category_name;

It looks like you meant to build your array like this instead:

```
$health_array[] = array(
    "num_problems" => $num_problems,
    "category_id" => $category_id,
    "category_name" => $category_name
);
```

This makes an array of arrays, where previously you were overwriting the keys of the same array for each iteration.